# how to remove space in string list python

Tags: python, list, replace, split, space

So i have list contains with 1 string.

> biner_pass = ['00001111000000000000111111111111
> 00001111111111111111000011111111    11111111111100000000000000000000
> 11111111111111110000111111111111']

all i want is to **remove the space** and **join all the binary**.

i was trying using
`binerpass = ''.join(biner_pass.split(' '))` or `biner_pass.replace(" ", "")` but it cannot work. so how to remove space?

Comment: biner_pass is a list, you need to access the first element. `biner_pass[0].replace(" ", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is the 0-th element of a list with 1 element. Therefore you need

```
biner_pass[0].replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You can use `replace`.

```
biner_pass = ['0000111100000000000011111111111100001111111111111111000011111111 1111111111110000000000000000000011111111111111110000111111111111']
biner_pass[0] = biner_pass[0].replace(" ", "")
print(biner_pass)
```

Output:

```
['00001111000000000000111111111111000011111111111111110000111111111111111111110000000000000000000011111111111111110000111111111111']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it for each element of the list

```
biner_pass = [b.replace(' ','') for b in biner_pass]
```

Answer (score 0):

`binary` will be a string that conatains `1` and `0` without `spaces`

```
binary = "".join(biner_pass).replace(" ", "")
```